# I need resources to fully understand ECS design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, 2d, game-engine, entity-component-system

so I'm new to the game making world and I come from object oriented preceptive on things but I want learn every thing about entity component system pattern ,how it works ,how to draw the diagrams and finally how to apply it to a 2d Godet game?
if you have any good resources please mention them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links you may find helpful:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system
- http://artificials.ch/entity-component-system-are-crazy-cool/